# javascript document.getElementById(id).src = ??? does not work since php creation of html

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic, web

I've recently changed my website from static (only html + css) to use php to generate the html allowing me to examply have a gallery showing all images in a specific folder etc.

My javascript

```
function makeBigSimple(id){

var src = document.getElementById(id).src;

document.getElementById("imageForShow").src = src;

}
```

My php just echo out the html. The part you'll be interested in is this html.

```
<div class="bigImage" id="bigImage" style="background-color: rgba(26,18,255,0.4)">
    <img id="imageForShow" src="images/gallery/showOff1.jpg" alt="Big Image" onLoad="resize('imageForShow','bigImage')">
</div>
<div class="smallImages">
    <ul>
        <li><img id="image0" src="images/gallery/showOff1.jpg" onClick="makeBigSimple('image0')" alt="Click to Enlarge" onLoad="resize('image0')"/></li>
        <li><img id="image1" src="images/gallery/showOff2.jpg" onClick="makeBigSimple('image1')" alt="Click to Enlarge" onLoad="resize('image1')"/></li>
        <li><img id="image2" src="images/gallery/showOff3.jpg" onClick="makeBigSimple('image2')" alt="Click to Enlarge" onLoad="resize('image2')"/></li>
        <li><img id="image3" src="images/gallery/showOff4.jpg" onClick="makeBigSimple('image3')" alt="Click to Enlarge" onLoad="resize('image3')"/></li>
        <li><img id="image4" src="images/gallery/showOff5.jpg" onClick="makeBigSimple('image4')" alt="Click to Enlarge" onLoad="resize('image4')"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

These images are genereated by searching a folder for .png and .jpg gfiles, if they pass these parameters they are put in an array and for each item in that array an list item with the parameter is added. Also i have a counter which is seen with "image1, image2" etc.

I've tried to make a printout of document.getElementById("bigImageForShow").src both before (showing my first image (images/gallery/showOff1.jpg)) and after.

the output after is actually the picture i've clicked on on my website. But the src dont change on the visual side, and if i inspect the "big image" element, I still have the src of the starting image, even tho document.getElementById("bigImageForShow").src says otherwise.

Comment: If the listener passes a  reference to the element it's on using `makeBigSimple(this)` then the function reduces to `function makeBigSimple(el){document.getElementById("imageForShow").src = el.src}`.

Comment: That is true, actually did that on a similar system the other day, thanks for the tip

Comment: Found the answer, In the 1st line inside the php script like this

    <?php
    self::makeSite();

Which was the name of the main method for creating the site, made it to not function, after i deleted that line everything worked. Donno why that is tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, In the 1st line inside the php script like this

```
<?php
self::makeSite();
```

Which was the name of the main method for creating the site, made it to not function, after i deleted that line everything worked. Donno why that is tho.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you testing your page in IE?  it probably works in chrome, IE has a nasty tendency to not show the new image when you update it via javascript.  The way around this is to trick IE into not caching the image by adding a url param to the image call with something that is constantly changing (the time):

```
function makeBigSimple(id){

    var src = document.getElementById(id).src;

    // may not be bad idea to console log or alert this value to test it is correct
    // remove when done debugging
    alert(src);

    document.getElementById("imageForShow").src = src + '?forceIeLoad=' + new Date().getTime());

}
```

also if you have jQuery loaded you can try setting the src this way, may have better results:

```
var src = $('#' + id).attr('src');
$('#imageForShow').attr('src', src  + '?forceIeLoad=' + new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: I've only tested in chrome to be honest. And I donno anything about Jquary yet, I'm general a backend programmer, just figling with some frontend stuff. Also i have done a lot of console.logs to test values.